# bottom overflowed by 1000 pixels

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make a header (picture with a card half inside pic and half outside and it worked in a stack.

but I'm in trouble when I have to make many containers below so when adding below the stack im having bottom overflowed.

I removed from code the unnecessary code so u can test it in your editor for help :)

any one can help me??

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ServiceDetails extends StatefulWidget {

    @override
    _ServiceDetails createState() => _ServiceDetails();
}

class _ServiceDetails extends State<ServiceDetails> {

   @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      var h = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
      var w = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
        return Scaffold(
          body: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: Stack(
                    children:[
                      Column(
                        children:[
                          Container(
                            height: h * .4,
                            width: w,
                          //  color: Colors.grey[50],
                            child: Image.asset('images/hairdresser1.jpg', fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,)
                          ),
                          new Container(
                            height: h * .0,
                            color: Colors.grey[50],
                          )
                        ]
                      ),
                      Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                        padding: new EdgeInsets.only(
                          top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .33,
                          right: 15.0,
                          left: 15.0
                        ),
                        child: Container(
                          height: 150,
                          child: Card(
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                            ),
                            elevation: 0.0,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                  Container(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, bottom: 5, top: 20),
                                    child: Text(
                                      "Hair Dresser",
                                      style: new TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                        fontSize: 20,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                                      )
                                    )
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, bottom: 5),
                                    child: Text(
                                      "With our proffisional barbers, new experience is guaranteed",
                                      style: new TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.grey,
                                        fontSize: 13
                                      )
                                    )
                                  ),
                              ],
                            )
                          )
                        )
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ),
                Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    child: Card(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                      ),
                      elevation: 0.0,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                            Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, bottom: 5, top: 20),
                              child: Text(
                                "Frequently Used",
                                style: new TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontSize: 15,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                                )
                              )
                            ),
                            Divider(),
                            Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                              height: 210,
                              width: w,
                            )
                        ],
                      )
                    )
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    child: Card(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                      ),
                      elevation: 0.0,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                            Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, bottom: 5, top: 20),
                              child: Text(
                                "Frequently Used",
                                style: new TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontSize: 15,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                                )
                              )
                            ),
                            Divider(),
                            Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                              height: 210,
                              width: w,
                            )
                        ],
                      )
                    )
                  ),
                )
             ]
            )
        );
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your column with `SingleChildScrollView` and widget tree be like

```
Scaffold
  -SingleChildScrollView
    - Column
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `SingleChildScrollView` To scroll the page.

SingleChildScrollView requires a scroll controller to change your code as follows

```
class _ServiceDetails extends State<ServiceDetails> {
   ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();
   @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      var h = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
      var w = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
        return Scaffold(
          body: Scrollbar(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              controller: scrollController,
              child: Column(
                  ------------------------------
             ),
           ),
         ),
      );
   }
}
```